# How do I return the count of the strings in a given pre-defined string array in C?

Tags: c

```
typedef char String[100];

int main
{ 
    String strArray[] = {"one", "two", "three"};
    int numStrings = countStrings(strArray);
    printf("count: %d\n", numStrings);
    return 0;
}

int countStrings(String strArray[]) // doesnt work
{
    int count = sizeof(strArray) / sizeof(strArray[0])
    return count;
}
```

Comment: If this is CS50 `String`, then what do you think the resulting type for `typedef char String[100];` is? Other than using an initializer or assigning a string-literal address -- how are you going to allocate for each element? Instead of the *empty-string* discussed as a sentinel, as you have it, you need `NULL` as that choice, e.g. `String strArray[] = {"one", "two", "three", NULL};` Then you can loop `count` with `int count = 0; while (strArray[count]) { count++; } return count;`

Comment: This question is answered here many times. A function **cannot** determine the length of the array passed to it as a parameter. You need to do something else.

Answer (score 2):

This is because when you pass the array to `countStrings`, it decays to `char **`, which carries no information about how long the array it points to is. You need to pass that information to the `countStrings` function.

Within `main`, `strings` is still an array and `sizeof` will do what you expect.

```
int main(void) {
    char *strings[] = {"one", "two", "three"};

    size_t num_strings = sizeof(strings) / sizeof(*strings);

    some_function(strings, num_strings);
}
```

Short answer: finding the length of an array is easy. It doesn't make sense to find the "length" of a *pointer* which is what your function receives.

Comment: it has to be a function and returns the count to the main function sadly

Comment: It's much less likely that you are expected to do this than that you've misinterpreted an assignment.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass an array to a function, it decays to a pointer to its first element. In C such a pointer does not "know" how many elements it points to. Therefore, you cannot count the elements by just this pointer.

One possible solution is the addition of a special element, which marks the end of the array.

In your case, you can use an empty string. This can be a `String` of length 0. Its first character is the end-of-string marker `'\0'`.

```c
int countStrings(String strArray[])
{
    for (int count = 0; strArray[count][0] != '\0'; count++) {
        /* nothing to do here */
    }
    return count;
}
```

Please note that this solution **will** access memory out-of-bounds (beyond the given array), if the array misses the end-of-array marker!

Feel free to use any other string as the marker.

---

As you might notice, the same principle is used with C strings. Even though a `char` array (your `String`) can have a capacity, you cannot store the actual length in it. When you pass a `String` to a function, the function receives the decayed pointer to the first `char`. The end of the string is marked by the special character `'\0'`.

All string functions of the C standard library expect this special character.

---

You will find another usage of this principle in the arguments given to `main()`. The standards says in chapter 5.1.2.2.1:

> `argv[argc]` shall be a null pointer.

So you have two options to iterate over all program arguments:

1. Counting from 0 to `argc - 1`;
2. Looping until `argv[argc] == null`.

And in chapter J.5.1 "Environment arguments":

> In a hosted environment, the `main` function receives a third argument, `char *envp[]`, that points to a null-terminated array of pointers to `char`, each of which points to a string that provides information about the environment for this execution of the program (5.1.2.2.1).

Because no `envc` (count of environment variables) is given, you can only iterate until you find the `null` pointer.

---

Other languages provide other solutions. Their arrays are more complex and *can* actually hold the number of elements.

Comment: Unclear from the question but if `String` is the CS50 `string`, then the original `typedef` in `cs50.h` is `typedef char *string;` meaning you may have `char **` instead of `char (*)[100]` which means the OP would need to assign and empty-string string-literal to be able to use `'\0'` as a sentinel. If not, you nailed it -- and already have my vote.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The type definition of `String` is at the top of the provided source. ;-) I had started to edit the tags to add "cs50", but cancelled after noticing that.

Comment: Duh.... smacks self :) . Looked right over it confusing CS50 `string` with `String`. Damn CS50 for that typedef - causes nothing but trouble....

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yeah. I marked the tag as "ignore" years ago. There are by far too many very low quality questions, partly caused by the low quality of CS50.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help! I was able to do it using this function.

```c
int countStrings(String strArray[])
{
  int i = 0, count = 0;
  
  while (*strArray[i] != '\0')
  {
    count++;
    i++;
  }
  
  return count;
}
```

Comment: OatiesMilk, This is poor code.  It attempts access outside `strArray[]`.  (UB).  It would be OK if `String strArray[] = {"one", "two", "three", ""};`

Comment: OatiesMilk, A more common approach would use `String strArray[] = {"one", "two", "three", NULL};` and `while (strArray[i] != NULL)`.  Even better, pass in the array length as suggested by others.